Why an error or problem is showing in the default code in layout.tsx
I have started a full stack project using nextjs, shadcn ui and others
why in the default already written code its showing an error
in the layout.tsx file in the Metadata from next
This is the problem, I am able to proceed in the start but this error is making me angry
Error from VS code
Help me in rectifying this error

have you tried to restart your typescript engine? or even VSCode itself?
